# How to insert underscore into a string before an upper case letter using perl

Tags: perl

Hi I have a String $string = "insertUnderScore";
now i need _ to be inserted before the upper case letter.
output should be like this:

```
$string = "insert_Unser_Score";
```

Can any one help me please?

Comment: Did you try anything yourself? Or did you just head straight to SO to ask someone to do your work for you?

Comment: I dont have any clue how to start with. I'm just new to perl and trying some new stuffs!!

Comment: Then perhaps http://perl-tutorial.org/ would have been a better place to go first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
my $string = "insertUnderScore";
$string =~ s/([A-Z])/_$1/g;
print $string;
```

Or

```
$string =~ s/(?=[A-Z])/_/g;
```